# Does the second const matter in void f(char const * const p)?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

A function declared

```
void f(const char * const p) { ... }
```

means that it takes a constant pointer to a constant character. But, with the variable `p` scoped only within the function itself and its usage hidden from the callee, does it matter if the second `const` is there?

In other words, wouldn't the following be semantically identical to the first from the perspective of the callee?

```
void f(const char *p) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first const indicates that you can't change the data is pointing to, the second indicates that this pointer can't be overwritten.

So, for a caller of this function, it doesn't matter.
For the implementation of the function, it can be useful, though it will only have effect locally.

Answer (score 2):

The second `const` (the one after the `*`) doesn't matter from the callee point of view.

But it does matter from the point of view of the function body. 
The second `const` makes sure that you can't make the pointer change its value (i.e. point to a different memory location).

It's comparable to declaring a simple primitive parameter as `const`, like in `void f(const int value) {}`

Comment: More generally, it's comparable (identical) to declaring _any_ local variable `const`, not just parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You tell the compiler that you won't modify `p` in that function. This allows the compiler certain optimizations, e.g. if `p` is already in a register, there's no need to save it and no need to allocate a new register.

It also causes the compiler to issue a diagnostic should you attempt to modify `p`, eg. `++p` or `p = ...` because that violates the promise you made.

Comment: It doesn't _allow_ the compiler to do the optimizations you mentioned. Even if it's non-const, the compiler can simply look whether the variable is modified inside the function, and if it's not, do the same optimizations.

Comment: @zenith Good point. Maybe *hint* might be a better word. But it certainly allows the compiler to skip all that is-p-constant checking, so it does allow a certain compile-time optimization.

Comment: Yes, it optimizes the optimization process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe so. The additional `const` here only means that in the implementation of `f`, the implementer is not allowed to reassign `p` to point to some other character or C-style string.